# Define a sequence of continuous functions on a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Tychonoff space, and $x\in X$ a non-isolated point of $X$ (I think this condition is not necessary).

Choose $x_n,y_n\in X$ such that $y_i\neq x_n$ and $x_n\neq y_n$ and $y_n\neq x_i$ for each $n,i\ge 1$.

There exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of continuous real-valued functions on $X$ satisfying the following conditions for every $n\ge 1$.

1) $|f_n|\le 1/2^n$

2) $f_n(x)=f_n(x_k)=f_n(y_k)=f_n(y_n)=0$ for each $k<n$.

3) $f_n(x_n)=\pm{1/2^n}$ where $f_n(x_n)$ and the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(f_k(x_n)-f_k(y_n))$ have the same sign.

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: You neglected to include a question. You just listed some statements and said "Any hint?". :)

Comment: What is that long string of inequations supposed to mean? What exactly is not equal to what, exactly, and exactly when?

Comment: My question is how to prove that there exists such a sequence. Clearly, we must use that $X$ is completely regular, and that the points are closed. But I don't know exactly how. (I'm sorry for my english).

Comment: What does "$y_i ≠ x_n ≠ y_n ≠ x_i$ for each $n,i\ge 1$ mean? I still can't make head or tail of it.

Comment: For each $n,i\ge 1$, we have $y_i\neq x_n$ and $x_n\neq y_n$ and $y_n\neq x_i$.

Comment: Please edit your post accordingly, after which we can delete these silly comments.

Comment: It is already edited.

Answer (score 0):

> Clearly, we must use that X is completely regular, and that the points are closed.

It seems that it suffices to consider a functionally Hausdorff space $X$. I recall that a space $X$ is *functionally Hausdorff* if for every distinct points $x,y\in X$ there exists a continuous function $f:X\to[0;1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. It is clear that any Tychonoff space is functionally Hausdorff.

I see no big problems in a construction of a sequence $\{f_n\}$ satisfying Conditions 1-3 
by induction on $n$. In the following construction I suppose that even if the sum in Condition 3 is equal to zero then its sign is defined as “+” or “–“. But, if you’ll insist that this sum should be non-zero, then we can try to modify the construction.

On the $n$-th step of the induction we do the following. Since the space $X$ is functionally Hausdorff, for each point $y\in Y=\{x, x_1, x_2,\dots, x_{n-1}, y_1, y_2,\dots, y_{n-1}, y_n\}$ there exists a continuous function $f_y:X\to [0;1]$ such that $f_y(y)=0$ and $f_y(x_n)=1$ (of course, we have to have $x\not=x_n$, because i the opposite case Conditions 2 and 3 contradict each other).  The sign $A$ of the sum form condition 3 is already defined. Put 
$f_n=A\cdot 1/2^n\prod_{y\in Y} f_y$.